# fscanf c - segmentation fault

Tags: c, file, scanf

the problem is to read from a file(the files are read in command line, linux) a character, then a tic tac toe matrix. then i want to return what i read (just a small test). i got segmentation fault. from what i've searched, the problem was a new line, so i consumed it with dummy. the same answer came. i checked if the files are opened correctly. i'd appreciate some help, thank you.

```
o
- x o
o x o
- - x
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     FILE *src, *dest;
     int i,j;
     char s[2];
     char* dummy;
     char* m[3][3];
     src=fopen(argv[1],"r");
     dest=fopen(argv[2],"w");
     fscanf(src,"%s",s);
     fscanf(src,"%s",dummy);    
     for(i=0;i<3;i++)
     {
         for(j=0;j<3;j++)
         {
              fscanf(src,"%s",m[i][j]);
         }
         fscanf(src,"%s",dummy);
     }
     for(i=0;i<3;i++)
         for(j=0;j<3;j++)
             fprintf(dest,"%s",m[i][j]);

fclose(src);
fclose(dest);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: HInt: Where does `m[i][j]` point to?

Comment: None of your `char*` point at valid (allocated) memory -> *undefined behavior*

Comment: *i checked if the files are opened correctly* - where? You are not doing any error checking at all: not of `argc` nor `fopen` nor `fscanf`...

Comment: Following the comment from Sourav Ghosh, `dummy` is also uninitialised. `fscanf(src,"%s",s)` is safe, but only for a string of length 1 . . .

Comment: i cheked if the files are opened correctly, but i felt unnecesary to copy it here, as it doesn't affect the rest.